# post-per-page and offset not working

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

This is my code, why cant i get post per page and offset result ?.

```
<?php 
    $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'offset' => 3,
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'brands',
        'terms' => array('iHOME'),
        'field' => 'slug',
        ));
    query_posts($myquery);?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
<b><?php the_title();?></b>
<p><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'category', true ) ); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it's `<?php` not `>?php`

Comment: @ShihabMalayil here is your solution: [MARKDOWN HELP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Please, get into a habit to write your questions nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Your query args are messed up.  Posts per page and offset params are not part of the `tax_query` array.  Check out the [example in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => array('your_cpt'),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'terms' => array('iHOME'),
            'field' => 'slug',
            )
    ) 
);

$tax_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : $tax_query->the_post(); 

    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_title();
    echo excerpt(25); 
    echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'category', true ) ); 

endwhile; else: 
endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also, I couldn't really explain *why*, but I always see it written around here to avoid using `query_posts`, so I replaced that in my answer with `new WP_Query`.

One more thing, if you are querying for a post type other than posts, you'll need to define the `post_type` query parameter.

Comment: @helgatheviking- You are correct.  
'tax_query' => array(  .  
thank you very much. expecting more....!

Comment: What are you expecting more of?  The code should work now.

Comment: iam sorry,  i mean help me next time.  thank you.  tax_query' => array( ,you just missed =>.

Comment: We'll see. I'm only on here some of the time.  Fixed the typo.  Don't forget to mark as resolved if this solves your question.

Comment: sure, will do...

Comment: how can i mark this question as resolved ?. i can't see anywhere...

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  Checkbox next to my answer. Not sure how fast that appears since you are so new to the site.

Comment: I think you need at least 24 hours before you can mark a correct answer. Or it maybe more, i can't recall, but there is a waiting period.